# Drawer layout with two navigation views and selected item colours

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, navigationview

I have a drawer layout that needs to have two navigation views in it, because there's a couple of options that need to be aligned on top and another on the bottom, with a divider separating them.

I've managed to make it work, but now I have two different problems with my setup.

1) The first one, I can't change the selected items text color (the background color works as intented via a drawer selector, but for some reason, the selected item's text color is always colorPrimary)

2) The second one is trickier, since there's two navigation views, it can happen that there's a selected row on the first and on the second one, even though they all work loading fragments in the same container. Is there a way to manage that, when an item for the first navigation view is selected, the second navigation view's selected item gets deselected?

This is the drawer's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <!-- 1º Layout de la activity -->
    <include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>

    <!-- 2º Layout del drawer -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/container_navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:scrollIndicators="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/navigation_view"
                android:id="@+id/top_separator"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_separator"
                app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/navigation_bottom"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_separator"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_bottom"
                app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the top navigation view's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_tus_ofertas"
                android:title="@string/tus_ofertas"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_offer" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_movimiento_puntos"
                android:title="@string/movimiento_puntos"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_points"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_asociaciones"
                android:title="@string/asociaciones"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_flag"/>

        </group>
</menu>
```

Bottom navigation view's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_terminos"
            android:title="@string/terminos"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_document" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contacto"
            android:title="@string/contacto"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_email"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_valorar"
            android:title="@string/valorar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_rate_review"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_exit"
            android:title="@string/exit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_shutdown"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Selected item's background selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

The activity that calls the drawer and handles the events:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.tabs) TabLayout tabs;
    @Bind(R.id.drawer_layout) DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.container_navigation) NavigationView containerNavigator;
    @Bind(R.id.navigation_view) NavigationView navigationView;
    @Bind(R.id.navigation_bottom) NavigationView navigationBottom;
    @Bind(R.id.vsFooter) ViewStubCompat stub;

    ImageView userPicture;
    TextView userMail;

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Menu menu;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPagerFragment viewPagerFragment;
    Usuario currentUser;

    public Usuario getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        currentUser = UserApiManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getCurrentUser();

        viewPagerFragment = ViewPagerFragment.newInstance();
        setupToolbar();
        setupNavigationDrawer();

        ApiManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setupFooter(stub, currentUser.getIdLocalidad(), this);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout,viewPagerFragment).commit();

    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar!=null){
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_black);
            actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_title));

        }
    }

    private void setupNavigationDrawer() {

        View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
        userPicture = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_picture);
        userMail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_mail);

        userMail.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
        Picasso.with(this).load(currentUser.getImagenURL()).transform(new CircleTransformation()).into(userPicture);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_tus_ofertas:
                        showTabLayout();
                        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_title));
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout,viewPagerFragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_movimiento_puntos:
                        hideTabLayout();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("idcliente", currentUser.getId());
                        MovimientoPuntosFragment movimientoPuntosFragment = MovimientoPuntosFragment.newInstance();
                        movimientoPuntosFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.movimiento_puntos));
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, movimientoPuntosFragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_asociaciones:
                        hideTabLayout();
                        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.asociaciones));
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, AsociacionFragment.newInstance()).commit();
                        break;
                }
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
        navigationBottom.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_terminos:
                        hideTabLayout();
                        actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.terminos));
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, LegalesFragment.newInstance()).commit();

                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_contacto:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + getString(R.string.contacto_email));
                        intent.setData(data);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_valorar:
                        final String appPackageName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
                        try {
                            Log.i("url", "market://details?id=" + appPackageName);
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_exit:
                        break;
                }
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_over, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            case R.id.action_user:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PerfilUsuarioActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void hideTabLayout(){
        tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void showTabLayout(){
        tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The problem with the color I solved it with a selector, it didn't work before because I had a syntax error (selector tag inside the main selector tag).

This is the color selector's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF" android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:color="#E6000000" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

The second problem I solved it by programmatically deselecting the other navigationview's items onNavigationItemSelected.

This is the function I call:

```
public void deselectItems(NavigationView view){
    int size = view.getMenu().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        view.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

I know there must be a better way to solve the second problem, but this one worked.